# Cypher - return 1 'random' node from specific relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to build a Cypher query that returns ONE entry per 'comic'.

Basic structure is as follows:

```
(Comic)<-[]-(Media)-[]->(MediaType)
```

I want to grab 3 'random' comics and return only one Media per comic of said type. As a comic may have 100 medias of the media type, it's a little concerning. I could break this down into multiple queries, but I am sure there's a way for Cypher to do this through its own system.

My original code would do what it needed to, but if there were multiple medias of the same type, one comic would had the possibility of being returned multiple times.

The original Code:

```
MATCH (mt:MediaType{Name: {mediatype} })
<-[:Is_Media_Of]-(m:Media)-[:Is_Media_For]->(w:Webcomic)
WHERE w.ComicID <> toInt({comicid})
AND m.Status = 'Active'
RETURN m.URL as ImgURL, 
w.Name as ComicName, 
rand() as r 
ORDER BY r ASC Limit toInt({count}) ",
["mediatype"=>$AdType,"count"=>$Count,"comicid"=>$ComicID])
```

This would sometimes return:

```
'comic1' 'img'
'comic2' 'img'
'comic1' 'img2'
'comic3' 'img2'
'comic4' 'img1'
'comic3' 'img5'
```

I'm sure it's pretty straight forward and I'm missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Bruno's Code:

```
MATCH (mt:MediaType{Name: {mediatype}})
<-[:Is_Media_Of]-(m:Media)-[:Is_Media_For]->
(w:Webcomic) WHERE w.ComicID <> toInt({comicid}) 
AND m.Status = 'Active' 
WITH distinct m, w 
RETURN m.URL as ImgURL, w.Name as ComicName, rand() as r 
ORDER BY r ASC Limit toInt({count})
```

Result for Bruno's Code:

```
ImgURL                       ComicName           r
"ms-rot-d1517513337.jpg"    "MoonSlayer"    0.09929832004330252
"ms-rot-b1517513245.jpg"    "MoonSlayer"    0.17924831869113889
"ms-rot-e1517513507.jpg"    "MoonSlayer"    0.23860836768580007
"mrRotator021516985058.jpg" "Mailbox Rocketship"    0.29152315193261946
"rotator1517004270.png" "Grapple Seed"  0.3167179880041201
```

Current results:

[image]

Wanted results:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried grouping by media? `MATCH (mt:MediaType{Name: {mediatype}})<-[:Is_Media_Of]-(m:Media)-[:Is_Media_For]->(w:Webcomic)
WHERE w.ComicID <> toInt({comicid})
AND m.Status = 'Active'
WITH distinct m, w
RETURN m.URL as ImgURL, 
w.Name as ComicName, 
rand() as r 
ORDER BY r ASC Limit toInt({count})`

Comment: @BrunoPeres I have tried using collect and I've tried distinct, but because media and webcomic can both be distinct (3 different medias for one webcomic, all of which are their own nodes, I receive the same outcome. I will modify the answer to contain the first response I got when I ran the DISTINCT you mentioned

Comment: Can you create an [console](http://console.neo4j.org) with some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @BrunoPeres I think this is what you meant for console view?

Comment: Try it: `MATCH (mt:MediaType{Name: {mediatype}})<-[:Is_Media_Of]-(m:Media)-[:Is_Media_For]->(w:Webcomic)
WHERE w.ComicID <> toInt({comicid})
AND m.Status = 'Active'
WITH distinct w, mt, collect(m) as ms
RETURN ms[0].URL as ImgURL, 
w.Name as ComicName, 
rand() as r 
ORDER BY r ASC Limit toInt({count})`

Comment: I'm basically grouping by comic and collecting all medias into a list. Then I returning the first element of the list.

Comment: @BrunoPeres That is it. Thank you. I had done the collect in the return when I was attempting it. I guess that's where my logic fallacy was

Comment: You are welcome! I will answer your question with my solution, then, if it solved your issue, you can accept it as the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
MATCH (mt:MediaType{Name: {mediatype}})<-[:Is_Media_Of]-(m:Media)-[:Is_Media_For]->(w:Webcomic)
WHERE w.ComicID <> toInt({comicid})
AND m.Status = 'Active'
WITH distinct w, mt, collect(m) as ms
RETURN ms[0].URL as ImgURL, w.Name as ComicName, rand() as r
ORDER BY r ASC Limit toInt({count})
```

I'm basically grouping by comic and collecting all medias into a list. Then I'm returning the first element of the list.